# How to find file extension using UNIX?

Tags: unix, ksh

I need to find file extension for file to be processed using UNIX. The two file extension which i will be handling are '.dat' and '.csv'.

Please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my stab at this.

```
filename=file.dat
extension=$(echo ${filename}|awk -F\. '{print $2}')
if [ ${extension} == "dat" ]; then
   your code here
fi
```

Echo the variable ${filename} pipe that output to awk.  With awk reset the field separator to a . then pick up field 2 (the print $2 part)

Comment: why use `awk` when `find` is designed to solve this exact problem?

Answer (score 20):

```
find . -name "*.dat" -o -name "*.csv"
```

Finds in the current directory and recursively down, all files that end in those two extensions.

Comment: Lets say If I am having a single file 'test.dat', how do I find out that the current file is having '.dat' file extension. The above script will list all the files in .dat extension.

Comment: `find . -name test.dat` will find only files named `test.dat`

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want ?

```
find . -name "*.dat"
find . -name "*.csv"
```

Comment: Lets say If I am having a single file 'test.dat', how do I find out that the current file is having '.dat' file extension. The above script will list all the files in .dat extension.

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/bash-get-file-extension

Answer (score 2):

if you have the filename in a variable

```
filename = test.csv
```

then just use this to get the "csv" part:

```
echo ${filename##*.}
```

works for bash, try it in ksh

edit:

```
filename=test.csv
fileext=${filename##*.}
if [ fileext = "csv" ]; then
        echo "file is csv, do something"
    else
        if [ fileext = "dat" ]; then
            echo "file is dat, do something" 
        else
            echo "mhh what now?"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: I dont not need the file name with out extension... I need to find out what is the extension of the time which I will be processing.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path -type f \( -name "*.dat" -o -name "*.csv" \) | while read -r file
do
   echo "Do something with $file"
done
```